# Why are multiple clicks being registered from a single click in an incremental fashion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm running into an unexpected issue. But aren't we all? First post, thank you to the community!:

Goal: within a `<div></div>`, using
`onclick="$(this).on('click', function() { console.log('foo') });"`,
I would like to cause a sibling div to `toggle()`. I have separate code written for that, that would replace the `console.log()` I have here, but when I tested this with the console.log, I noticed something strange happening in the dev tools.

- Each click registers multiple logs.
- Each additional click would increment one more click than the previous click. confusing? here's how it went:
- 1st click: no log made to the console
- 2nd click: 2 console logs
- 3rd click: 3 console logs (5 total)
- 4th click: 4 console logs (9 total)
- 5th click: 5 console logs (14 total)

[picture of console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWQRw.png)

What am I not aware of that's causing this? When I replace the `console.log` with `$(differentDiv).toggle()`, the animation behaves very strangely, I'm assuming due to these multiple clicks registering.

NOTE: I understand best practices do not recommend this method, but my company's CMS is very frustratingly limited and requires these types of practices. Additionally, I am trying to avoid separate `<script>` tags because the CMS makes it difficult for my fellow employees who are non-web developers to input javascript separately. Thank you for constructive comments.

Comment: Always post the full code so that other developers can replicate and see your issue easily

Comment: It looks like with each click, you are adding an extra event listener. Get rid of the onclick and move your $('element').on('click', function()...  into a $(document).ready() wrapper

Comment: This is why you should not bind events inside of other events.

Comment: I understand best practices do not recommend this method, but my company's CMS is very frustratingly limited and requires these types of practices. Additionally, I am trying to avoid separate  <script> tags because the CMS makes it difficult for my fellow employees who are non-web developers to input javascript separately. There's a reason I'm trying this method.

Answer (score 2):

This is a fun bug to run into!  Right now,  every click adds one more click handler.  So for the first click,  there are no click handlers.  You click the button,  that codes is run,  and now you have a click handler.  With every subsequent click,  you add another handler, and each will be run when the button is clicked.

Either do just the console.log / function call:

```
onClick="console.log('foo')"
```

Or,  bind the click handler separately.

```
<button id="myButton" />
<script>
    $('#myButton').on('click', function() { console.log('foo') });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! I'm surprised I haven't run into this before. Is it really a bug like you say, or is this something I should have known? I actually have something functional using your separate click handler suggestion, and I've written 20 unique IDs because there are potentially multiple divs that are to hide/show based on clicks. Someone asked, what if I wanted 100 divs, would they each need their own handler written? I am experimenting with the inline onclick using `this` selector to find a way to generate elements that could be independent of a separate script.

Comment: By bug,  I just mean it wasn't working the way you thought / expected it to.  You don't run across many real 'bugs' at the language level.  Checkout how event binding works in jQuery.  You could give each div the same class, then bind one event to the class `$('.myClass').on('click'.....`  when the click handler is invoked,  jQuery will set `this` in that function to be the div that was clicked.

Comment: Just for inlining it,  try `onClick="$(this).toggle('className')"`   when you inline it like that,  there is no need to rebind it,  that code will get run when the button is clicked.

Comment: will try to simplify it and take out the extra event. thanks for your help!